# Django Rest Framework nested APIView route

Tags: django-rest-framework

If I have a ModelViewSet at

```
/foo
```

is it possible to use an APIView at a url under that?  Example APIView would be at

`/foo/count`?

I tried registering the url with Django but it didnt work except if I changed the /foo to something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@list_route` decorator

```
from rest_framework.decorators import list_route

class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @list_route()
    def count(self, request):
       ...
       return Response(...)
```

It will append new endpoint to viewset url `/foo/count/` like you want
[Docs about extra actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Answer (score 0):

It worked if I registered the url with Django before I registered the ModelViewSet url patterns.

```
urlpatterns += [
url(
    regex=r'^foo/count/',
    view=Foo.as_view(),
    name='foo_count',
    )
]
urlpatterns += foo_urlpatterns
```